# Leafletjs - Presence of a leaflet point in a array

Tags: javascript, jquery, underscore.js, leaflet

I have a leaflet point (L.latLng) and I would like to know if there is an occurrence of it inside an array of leaflet point.

```
o.LatLng {lat: 48.8589507, lng: 2.2775168}
```

I tried using JQuery ($.inArray) or underscorejs (_.intersection) but I don't know how to compare the lat and the lng at the same time.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @ghybs points out, [`.equals`](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#latlng-equals) can compare two instances of `L.LatLng`. In order to check if an equal instance exists in an array, you'll need to use [`Array.find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) or iterate through the items:

```
latLngToBeFound = L.latLng( 48, 2 );

latLngArray = [
    L.latlng( 58, 9 ),
    L.latlng( 32, 14 ),
    L.latlng( 48, 2 ),
    L.latlng( 0, 15 )
];

var exists = !!latLngArray.find( function(i){
    return latLngToBeFound.equals(i);
} );
```

[See this code in work](http://playground-leaflet.rhcloud.com/ber/edit?html,console).

Comment: Thanks a lot! Out of curiosity, what's the notation "!!" for ?

Comment: `!!` is `not not` - it will cast a truthy/falsy value to a `Boolean` type. `Array.find` returns either `undefined` or a array item, but you probably want a Boolean instead.

Answer (score 1):

You are probably looking for [`.equals()` method](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#latlng-equals) of `L.LatLng` objects:

> Returns `true` if the given LatLng point is at the same position (within a small margin of error).

Answer (score 0):

Use underscore find function.

```
 _.find(arrayOfPoints, function(point){
      return point.lat === myLat && point.lon === myLon; 
 });
```